# IE adds encoded values to encodeURIComponent in every AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, encoding, hash

I am passing a value for example "Cats & Dogs" through a AJAX request.

I am applying `encodeURIComponent` to the value like: `encodeURIComponent("Cats & Dogs");`

Then I set the browser hash to this value for AJAX bookmarking. It works well in Firefox - in the the hash it appears as `#value=Cats %26 Dogs`, however in IE it appears as `Cats%20%26%20Dogs`, this causes a problem when I attempt to read the hash and resend it in a AJAX call, IE keeps adding more encoded values so the previous value becomes `Cats%2520%2526%2520Dogs` and then `Cats%2520%2526%2520Dogs` and so on...

This does not occur in Firefox.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found my problem. I was not decoding the encoded value before setting it as the hash.